# viewing buffer contents in a debug watch window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, watch

Is there a way to enter expression in debug watch window to see a portion of a buffer having only a pointer to it? i.e first 200 elements of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure. If you have a buffer named, say, `buf`, write this in the watch window:

> buf, 200

And VS will show you the first 200 elements of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a memory window:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d2www5s(v=vs.90).aspx